# Copying a row in the same table without having to type the 50+ column names (while changing 2 columns)

Tags: sql, oracle

During my job, I usually have to copy rows while changing their primary key and giving them a new stamp and maybe changing the foreign key.

The problem is I don't want to type all the column names while doing;

```
insert into table_name
select pk_seq.nextval, 
       'foreign-key', 
       col3,
       col4...col51
  from table_name
 where pk_id = "original_primary_key"
```

And if i do * in the select statement i won't be able to update the first 2 columns...

Is there any way to do how I want to do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well it may not be much less verbose, but this PL/SQL is an option:

```
begin
  for r in (select *
              from table_name
             where pk_id = 'original_primary_key')
  loop
    r.pk := pk_seq.nextval;
    r.fk := 'foreign-key';
    insert into table_name values r;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Nice. Note for people who are not on Oracle 11g, the line `r.pk := pk_seq.nextval;` should be replaced by `select pk_seq.nextval into r.pk from dual;`

Comment: A BULK COLLECT / BULK INSERT cursor might work even better.  PL/SQL in 10g+ implicitly bulks the implicit cursor, but you're still doing a PL/SQL -> SQL -> PL/SQL context switch on every insert.

Comment: @Adam Musch: The cursor should process at most one row, since the `where` clause has an equality test on the primary key. With only one row, bulk collect/bulk insert would not buy anything.

Comment: I completely didn't notice the "and pk = 'primary key value'"; I had the arbitrary/general case in my head.

Comment: @schnatterer I rolled back your edit - I don't see why my answer's code has to be in your favoured style!?

Comment: @TonyAndrews It's not *my* favoured style. I believe(d) it to be defacto-standard for oracle

Comment: It is a common style promoted by PL/SQL guru Steven Feuerstein but it is not compulsory, and many programmers (including Tom Kyte) prefer not to have UGLY uppercase KEYWORDS all OVER THE place! :-)

Comment: I didn't no there were different denominations within PL/SQL syntax formatting ;)

Answer (score 15):

Based on [Tony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780383/copying-a-row-in-the-same-table-without-having-to-type-the-50-column-names-whil/3780478#3780478):

We know that at most one row will be returned since we are searching on primary key. And assuming that a valid key value is specified, at least one row will be returned. So we don't need the loop:

```
declare
    r table_name%ROWTYPE;
begin
    select *
    into r
    from table_name
    where pk_id = "original_primary_key";
-- 
    select pk_seq.nextval into r.pk_id from dual;
     -- For 11g can use instead: r.pk_id := pk_seq.nextval;
    r.fk_id := "new_foreign_key";
    insert into table_name values r;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry - it's an all or nothing affair.
There isn't anything between `SELECT *` and list the specific columns, it's one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

You could just query the data dictionary to generate the SQL for you.

```
SELECT 'tbl.' || column_name || ','
FROM   user_tab_columns
WHERE  table_name = 'MYTABLE'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

Get the result of this query, paste into your SQL statement, adapt as necessary, and voila.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 'temp' table, update two columns and do an insert-select from this 'temp' table.

Eaxmple:

```
create table temptemp as 
select *
  from table_name
 where pk_id = "original_primary_key"

update temptemp
set col1 = ...
,   col2 =....

insert into table2
select * from temptemp;
```

Comment: This method is helpful with big data sets. Memory consumption is not significant.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple stored procedure that take a table name and using the data dictionary writes the select statement text for you (the text of the select). Then copy, paste and Modify.