# Copying a row in the same table (within a loop of array of tables)

Tags: oracle, plsql

There was a great answer from @ShannonSeverance on this question

[Copying a row in the same table without having to type the 50+ column names (while changing 2 columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780383/copying-a-row-in-the-same-table-without-having-to-type-the-50-column-names-whi)

that showed how to dynamically copy a row within a table to the same table (changing the pk)

```
declare
r table_name%ROWTYPE;
begin
select *
into r
from table_name
where pk_id = "original_primary_key";
-- 
select pk_seq.nextval into r.pk_id from dual;
 -- For 11g can use instead: r.pk_id := pk_seq.nextval;
r.fk_id := "new_foreign_key";
insert into table_name values r;
end;
```

I would like to apply this approach but within a function that is called each time from within an array of table names

So basically I can do the select using execute immediate - but how do I declare 'r'? Can I replace 'table_name' in the code with a variable that is passed to the function?

```
table(1)="Table1";

table(2)="Table2";

for t 1..table.count loop
 CopyTableContacts(table(i));
end loop;
```

TIA

Mike

Comment: That is a good question.  I am not sure if there is a way to do this.

Comment: The line in the solution code, r.fk_id := "new_foreign_key";
holds the key to your answer, it is clearly telling us the solution is meant for a specific table "table_name". 

Any other table and you are looking at a different (set) of foreign keys for sure... reason why the same cannot possibly be dynamic to the extent you asked. My 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks @user2275460 - by a strange set of circumstances, ALL the tables have the same primary key!!! But I fully understand what you are saying - it would be so nice to have a generic function "CopyRow" that you could pass a table name to (and even perhaps the primary key column name(!) - I'm coming at PL/SQL from a Java background so maybe it's up to me to change my way of thinking?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have amended my function slightly

I now build 2 arrays

1 - the list of table names from the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table
2 - for each table in array1, I build a comma delimited list of the column names from the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table

So I end up with 2 arrays (example...)

```
tableName(1) = 'MEMBER'
tableName(2) = 'SALARY'

tableColumns(1) = 'ID, SURNAME, SEX, DOB'
tableColumns(2) = 'ID, CURRENTSAL, BONUS, GRADE'
```

I then pass these 2 arrayvalues to my function and use some dynamic SQL during the looping of the tableName() array...

```
PROCEDURE CopyTableRow(inOrigMemNo NUMBER, inNewMemNo NUMBER, inTableName USER_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE, inTableString LONG) AS
selectString VARCHAR2(32000):=null;
newTableString LONG:=null;
insertTableString LONG:=null;
sqlResultCount NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
/*CHECK IF THERE IS AT LEAST ONE ROW TO COPY*/
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || inTableName || ' WHERE ID= ' || inOrigMemNo INTO sqlResultCount;
IF sqlResultCount > 0 THEN
  /*BUILD INSERT STATEMENT FOR EACH ROW RETURNED*/
  dbms_output.put_line('At least one row found on ' || inTableName || '(' || sqlResultCount || ')');

  newTableString    := REPLACE(inTableString, 'ID', 'REPLACE(ID, ID,' || inNewMemNo || ')');
  selectString      := 'SELECT ' || newTableString || ' FROM ' || inTableName || ' WHERE ID = ' || inOrigMemNo;
  insertTableString := 'INSERT INTO ' || inTableName || '(' || inTableString || ') (' || selectString || ')';
    END IF;
```

I am then left with an INSERT statement based on the table definition and value that I can execute

This seems to work fine and suits my current needs

*NOTE* - it only works if each table only has one row to copy. My next challenge is to cope with some of the tables returning multiple rows for the ID that require copying (which will be interesting seeing as I've painted myself into a non-cursor corner!)

Mike